# PHP Date to String to compare dates

Tags: php, mysql, string, date, compare

I only have basic PHP knowledge and I'm using PHP+Mysql and trying to check the difference in days between 2 dates; the 1st date is formatted by myself in the script as a string:

```
$f_entrega=$_POST['year1']."-".$_POST['month1']."-".$_POST['day1'];
```

The second date (`$f_dock`) which is the one causing the issue is taken from the mysql database which column is in DATE format. To compare the dates I do the following:

```
if(!empty($_POST["id"])){
    $f_entrega=$_POST['f_entrega_a']."-".$_POST['f_entrega_m']."-".$_POST['f_entrega_d'];
    $f_entr=$f_entrega;
    $mysqli=conectar();
    $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,f_dock FROM pt");
    $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($ids);$i++){
        do{
            if ($ids[$i]==$row["id"]){
                $f_dock=$row["f_dock"];
                break;
            }
        } while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc());     
        $error=0;
        var_dump($f_dock);
        $f_dock=strtotime($f_dock);
        $f_dock=date('Ymd',$f_dock);
        $f_entrega=$f_entr;
        $f_entrega=strtotime($f_entrega);
        $f_entrega=date('Ymd',$f_entrega);
        $f_dock=DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd',$f_dock);
        $f_entrega=DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd',$f_entrega);
        $dias_vendor=date_diff($f_dock,$f_entrega);
        $tat=$dias_vendor->format('%R%a');
```

Sometimes it works correctly, but other times I get Warning: `strtotime()` expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in [first line] and $tat is not correctly calculated and has strange values.
I've tried different solutions like `$f_dock=(string)$f_dock` before but finally the convertion always fails in some cases. Thanks in advance for any tip.

Comment: This error `Warning: strtotime()expects parameter 1 to be string` said that `$f_entrega` is empty or non valid string to format dates. You can control it viewing the value in a var_dump: `var_dump($f_entrega)` before the strtotime function. Tell us what is the result of this var_dump when script fails

Comment: The output for var_dump is the following: string(10) "2015-08-11"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you are getting is because the string you are entering is not a valid string for the `strtotime()` function to convert.

For instance `2015-08-31` will convert just fine, as will `today`, `tomorrow` or `+7 days`.

For more specific help you will need to tell us what the value of `$f_dock` is (as Marcos says in his comment, `var_dump($f_dock)` will get you this).

However, on to the solution:

```
$date1 = strtotime($f_dock); //timestamp in seconds
$date2 = strtotime($f_entrega); //same for the second date
$difference = $date1 - $date2; //difference in seconds between the dates
$days = floor($difference/86400);
```

`86400` is the number of seconds in a day, so find out how many seconds difference there is, then see how many days worth of seconds are in there and use `floor()` to round the number down. Job done.

Comment: The output for var_dump is the following:
string(10) "2015-08-11"

Comment: That works for me and should for you, even if there is a space after the 11. Is that code on your original post an exact copy and paste?

Comment: Yes it is...could be something wrong in the database that sometimes the f_dock is a string and others an object? The mysql database column is set as DATE, and the straction is always the same by "row=$result->fetch_asocc();"
The topic is that sometimes it fails and other it doesn´t...

Comment: I think we need to see more of the code to be able to help. $row = $result->fetch_assoc() will fetch each column unless you have specified only the date column in your MySQL query, for example, and if it is selecting all the data then some of those columns aren't dates and will throw errors when you try to use strtotime(). Can you update your original post to include ALL of the relevant code?

Comment: I´ve just pasted the complete code, the FOR sentence closes after the last line.

Comment: Okay, this row: `for ($i=0;$i<count($ids);$i++){` where are you declaring $ids?

Comment: $ids comes from a previous multi-select checkbox form which passes the amount of units ($id) you have to calculate this date differences, so if you select 3 units, the FOR loop will be done 3 times.

Comment: I´ve just done a test: First I selected only 1 unit and it worked, Second I selected 2 units and it worked, Third I selected 3 units and the error appeared. This is the var_dump output for the 3 $f_dock values:


string(10) "2015-05-21" string(10) "2015-05-22" object(DateTime)#4 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-05-22 15:53:31" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }
Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\modulus\pt\cls_pt.php on line 126


It´s like some data is in DATE format and other in DATETIME???

Comment: Also I´ve just tested if I olny select the unit that failed in the example above, it goes ok, but if I select more than one, the error appears again, so something is wrong in the loop, as if I select only 1 unit it never fails.

I´ve removed the line 11 (break;) and added a $resultado->data_seek(); after the last line, and I think now all the units are being correctly processed.

Thanks for the tips, and I´ll use that var_dump tool more often!